# register_nav_menus doesn't show menus in WordPress dashborad

Tags: wordpress

I have this code inside `functions.php` file.

```
function my_theme_setup()
{
    register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary-menu' => 'My Custome Primary Menu',
    'footer_menu' => 'My Custom Footer Menu'));
}
add_action('init', 'my_theme_setup');
```

but nothing appear inside appearance>menus in `WordPress` dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this function

`register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', 'My Custome Primary Menu');`

`register_nav_menu( 'footer_menu', 'My Custom Footer Menu');`

Do not wrap them into any function or hook

Hope this'll help you